# Laravel поддержка mysqli

Tags: mysqli, laravel

Laravel не поддерживает драйвер mysqli?

```
InvalidArgumentException in ConnectionFactory.php line 189:
Unsupported driver [mysqli]
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос впро БД mysql, то её Laravel, разумеется, поддерживает. Только название драйвера надо писать правильно.

Если вопрос про mysqli, то вопрос не имеет смысла. Фреймворк не должен поддерживать драйвер. Фреймворк должен предоставлять абстрактные методы для работы с БД, а уж на чем они там у себя внутри реализованы - разработчика не должно волновать.

Answer (score 0):

У Laravel своя обертка над pdo для работы с базами, в конфиге в параметре driver вы указываете сервер бд с которым хотите работать, то есть mysql, mssql и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете использовать драйвер mysqli в Laravel. Подозреваю, что причина может быть в переносе legacy приложения в современный фреймворк и нежелание изучать Eloquent. В таком случае, вы можете использовать MySQL запросы из старого приложения, используя фасад DB. Примеры из документации:

```
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);

$results = DB::insert('insert into users (id, name) values (?, ?)', [1, 'Dayle']);

$results = DB::update('update users set votes = 100 where name = ?', ['John']);
```